# is there a place to get/share notepad++ syntax highlighting?

Tags: notepad++

I'd like Notepad++ to correctly style my cshtml files (that's ASP.NET MVC Razor view engine files). Rather than tweak one myself, is there a place I can grab one that's already made? If I do end up tweaking one where should I share it?

Comment: it would be nice, could be boosted with sharing visual themes, settings "profiles", favourite plugins...

Comment: I had good results emailing the author. He is pretty responsive and included even syntax highlight tweaks i sent his way. He does appreciate if you have a public repo and other people start it or something...

Comment: Try SynWrite if you can't find syntax in notepadd++. That maybe help. You can see more at http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it in an SO post:

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files

No CSHTML there though.

Comment: What is CSHTML?

Comment: @Celeritas see OP

Comment: Were you able to make one?

Comment: Did you create one, if so you should share :)

Comment: @jeremysawesome Nope. I removed that from the answer. I'm using Jade these days for markup so don't really need it.

Comment: @Celeritas: CSHTML is the file extension for razor files for C#. Razor files for VB use VBHTML.

Comment: Updated link: project no longer primarily hosted at Sourceforge.