# Request Notepad++ (NPP) cshtml syntax highlight file

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I sometime have to open cshtml file in Notepad++ (NPP). As you may know, this cshtml file is generated when creating an asp.net web project (Razor or MVC). It is a mix of csharp syntax and HTML syntax. I would like to request a syntax highlight file to be imported/used in NPP. I have searched the web and there are few mentions of this cshtml file syntax highlight file. I have found this [SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/446866/is-there-a-place-to-get-share-notepad-syntax-highlighting), but still no CSHTML file.

I treat this as CS file, but it does not highlight the HTML part inside the file.

Comment: It is not available but it may be possible to create a new one. You can check [notepad++ issues](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) for further help.

Comment: Super User is not a script writing service. It’s also not a code highlighting definition writing service. This type of question is off-topic here and probably almost anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.